# How to insert custom date time in oracle using java?

Tags: java, oracle, date

Hi i have a column (type date).I want to insert custom date and time without using **Preparedstatement** .i have used

```
String date = sf.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
String query = "Insert into entryTbl(name, joinedDate, ..etc)  values ("abc", to_date(date, 'yyyy/mm/dd HH:mm:ss'))";
statement.executeUpdate(query);
```

but am getting **literal doesnot match** error. so even tried with **"SYSDATE"**.Its inserting only date not time.So how to insert the datetime using java into oracle?please any one help..

Comment: any specific reason to not use PreparedStatement?

Answer (score 1):

It is strongly recommended to use `PreparedStatement` to counter potential SQL injection attacks, instead of building raw SQL queries to interact with the database.

That said, you can specify the value for date column as a string in `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` format as well:

```
SimpleDateFormat sf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
String date = sf.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
String query = "INSERT INTO entryTbl(name, joinedDate, ..etc.,)  values ('abc', '" 
    + date + "', ...etc.,)";
statement.executeUpdate(query);
```

Comment: Because of lot columns in my table.We do not know lot of fields whether we put setInt() ,setString() and where fields also by using PreparedStatement.So we have used directly query to execute tat command...and above query also not able to inserting wat u mentioned...isthere any other way?

Answer (score 0):

I think `yyyy/mm/dd HH:mm:ss` should be updated as : `YYYY/MM/DD HH:MI:SS TZH:TZM` and use `to_timestamp`--[documentation here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions194.htm)

```
 String query = "INSERT INTO entryTbl(name, joinedDate, ..etc.,) "+
           "values ('abc', "+
           "TO_TIMESTAMP('"+dateString+"', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:MI:SS TZH:TZM'), etc.,)";
```

Comment: @shrr: Please share the dataString? Also share the new error after using the above syntax.